# Can not download mypublic wifi because of time out

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, vmware-workstation

I am trying to download a virtual router software mypublicwifi from this page
https://mypublicwifi.com/publicwifi/en/index.html on clicking this it redirects me to following (I have internet download manager integrated in my Edge browser)
http://127.0.0.1:1001/status/204+IDM
I get timed out.
[image: Timed out in downloading]
The connection does not even begin
[image]
I am trying to download it in a virtual machine running Windows 10.
The Network in VMware is running in bridged mode.
The network icon on my machine shows me 
[image: no internet in network3]
However I am able to post this question from the virtual machine itself.
I tried to ping google here is the result.
[image: ping hanged]
Following is the output of ncpa.cpl
[image]
I am able to run Psiphon3 on the virtual machine and all sites are opening properly. What could be the problem at my end. I use internet download manager 6.35 in Windows 10. What more should I check.
I am using VMware workstation 15 and Windows 10 as host OS and guest OS also Windows 10.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is "my computer" - that link will not leave your machine.

Comment: I understand but I did not do any thing it is happening automatically. I don't know if IDM extension has done this or some thing else has done it. I am occasionally facing this problem in my virtual machine that I see it is not able to connect to internet some how some proxy is set in it and then I manually go and disable all kind of proxy settings which it has acquired from some where. I suspect psiphon to set proxy each time when I psiphon connects to internet on this machine or this machine is infected by some virus. The scans though did not show me any thing.

Comment: See this>>>>>>>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zmxDaWWDSI

Comment: Turn off IDM and psiphon, one at a time to see what's causing the issue.